# AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'response'

Tags: python, discord.py

```
class MyView(View):  
    @discord.ui.button(label = 'Ping',style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def ping_button_callback(self, button, interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed = pingembed)
```

It was working fine, until today when I tryed to execute the command and it gave me that error

AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'response'

Before, he sent the message like this:

Ping Command!
This command will show the ping of the bot
For example:

> > .ping
> > Pong! 139 ms

Answer (score 4):

You swapped the arguments. The first argument (in this case button) is the `Interaction` instance. The second one (in this case interaction) is the `Button` instance

Comment: Ya i got the same problem as as kejax explained i swaped the position of interaction and button and then it work perfectly syntax is `async def send_message(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.button):`